# Activity: from home screen launch or back from the stack

Tags: android

How can I determine if my main/launcher activity has been invoked from the home screen or by backing up the activity stack?

I display a splash screen and would only like to show it when a user has arrived there from the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Make the splash screen be a separate activity. Have it be the one you have in the `LAUNCHER` category. And, when it advances to your next activity, have it `finish()` so it is no longer on the stack. Then, the only way the splash screen should be seen is if your program in not already running and Android starts from scratch.

Comment: This answer solves the problem, but I was hoping you'd actually give a solution that would answer the question: how to differentiate between an app that was relaunched from home screen, and the back button?